# Gi and dogi should be synonyms of uniform

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [gi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gi) and [dogi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogi) should be synonyms of the English version [uniform](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform). These are all the same concept, and all current questions tagged [uniform](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform) are also tagged [gi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gi).

Revisiting this years later now. Is there a reason to keep these concepts separate?

Comment: I could do this, but I'll leave it for the community to do instead.  I would actually change `uniform` to `training-uniform` just to be really explicitly clear, but let's see what everyone else says first.

Comment: Seconding slugster's comment.

Answer (score 3):

While gi and dogi are training uniforms, the inverse is not true. (Not all uniforms are gi or dogi.) We would either have to expand [uniforms](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniforms) to cover every type of uniform, or allow individual kinds of uniforms to crop up.

Personally, I think having a simple  [training-uniform](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training-uniform) for all kinds of uniform has potential to both hurt and help. I suspect we get the most gains with this tag if we advise people to also tag their questions with whatever martial art they are interested in. So [judo](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judo) and [training-uniform](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training-uniform) would be about Judogi and [brazillian-jiu-jitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brazillian-jiu-jitsu) would ask for about the uniform they wear in that martial art. If that usage guide is in place, I think it will work well. If that isn't there, I think the unified tag will waste people's time.

Comment: Although not all uniforms are gi/dogi, there are no current questions about uniforms that are not specifically gi/dogi.

Comment: @mattm It pays to think about the future.

Comment: Don't forget 'dobok' - Korean/taekwondo verision of gi/dogi/uniform!

Comment: @MikeP Yup, just another uniform for us to consider with this tag.

Comment: Ooh... does this mean I ought to create an `abadás` tag? :-D